# Why isn't useReducer state rendering new data successfully requested from API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input form that patches data. I would like the onSubmit function to send a render trigger to my useReducer that pulls data from my api get request and update my project with new data.

Right now the trigger is working but it's not causing a state re-render for the rest of the components. I know the trigger is working because of the successful api requests, but the new data is not showing up/

Here is the Parent component where the useReducer is. I then pass data from `getFinData` ran inside the `useEffect` to send data via state props to my Table component.

```
const initialState = {
    loading: true,
    error: '',
    data: []
}

const reducer = (state, action) =>
{
    switch (action.type)
    {
        case 'FETCH_SUCCESS':
            return {
                loading: false,
                data: action.payload,
                error: ''
            }
        case 'FETCH_ERROR':
            return {
                loading: false,
                data: {},
                error: "Something went wrong!"
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}



export const Bucket = () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)
    const { slug } = useParams();


    
    useEffect(() =>
    {
        getFinData(dispatch)(slug);
        console.log(state)
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
        <GetAboutBucketData /> //My input action lives deeply nested in GetAboutBucketData
        <GetBucketData  error={state.error} loading={state.loading} data={state.data}/>
        </>
    );
```

`getFindData` is it's own function in a different file.

```
export const getFinData = (dispatch) => (slug) => axiosInstance
        .get('bucket/fin-data/' + slug)
        .then(response => {
            dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: response.data })
            console.log('fired')
        })
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ERROR' })
        })
```

Here is `GetBucketData`:

```
function GetBucketData(props)
{
    const {data, loading, error} = props    
    return (
        <>
            <Tables error={error} loading={loading} data={data}/>
        </>
    );
};

export default GetBucketData;
```

my input `onSubmit` function where I want the request to cause a re-render for my useReducer.

```
  const onSubmit = (data, e) =>
  {  
    console.log(data);

    axiosInstance
      .patch(`bucket/add/symbols/` + slug + '/', {
        stock_list: data.stock_list.map(list=>list.symbol),
      })
      .then((res) =>
      {
        getFinData(dispatch)(slug);
      });
  };
```

How can I get my useReducers state to cause a re-render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the logic of the useEffect to a function, call that function in the useEffect as well as pass it down to the form so it can be called inside the *.then* callback inside the *onSubmit*.

**[UPDATE]**

**This is invalid as we have useReducer here from React not a Redux reducer.**

You could extract the function to a separate file and provide dispatch with a higher order function. Keep in mind this is not the cleanest solution, lifting the state and fetch function up would be better.

```
//bucket-api.js

export const getFinData = (dispatch) => (slug) => axiosInstance
        .get('bucket/fin-data/' + slug)
        .then(response => {
            dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: response.data })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ERROR' })
        })
```

Then in both files you would simply call it like this:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
getFinData(dispatch)(slug);
```

Comment: Is there another way I could do that without passing the data down? These companies are siblings.

Comment: You could use extract the function to an external module and import it in those 2 places. This would require passing the dispatcher as a dependency though, which is not the most elegant way. You could also use react-thunk and simply dispatch a thunk in those two places. The thunk would dispatch the request success action and trigger a rerender.

Comment: Could you show me an example how the extract function would look like on an external module?

Comment: If those are siblings you could also lift that state up, which would probably be the easiest one to implement.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Hey, I just tried your implementation. I couldn't get it to work as expected. I have added in my post updated code based off your recommendation code.

Comment: Could you describe what is happening?

Also, you should replace the content of useEffect so that it only contains the `getFinData(dispatch)(slug)`.

Comment: Okay I replaced the useEffect for the original useReducer method. Right now, when on submit is clicked, I'm getting the data working, but there does not seem to be a render updating data on the screen?

Comment: Are two requests being sent on submit? One for adding symbol and second for fetch finData?

Comment: Does the reducer gets fired?

Comment: It does get fired, based from a console.log().  I will update my comp tree right now in original post.

Comment: OK, I think I know what is happening. You're using useReducer from React and not Redux. This means the dispatch won't work, you would have to pass the dispatcher returned by the useReducer, which pose the same issue as the original. I would advise you to lift the reducer up the component tree.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense, just updated my post. I will lift it now.

Comment: I just lifted the useReducer to the Parent level, still its not causing the component to be re-rendered?

Comment: Is the state.data update after running the reducer? If so, it should rerender the Tables component.

Comment: Ahh I think thats the issue, how can I get the state to properly update here?

Comment: You need to pass it down from the parent component where the useReducer is lifted to. You could update the question with your current code so we're on the same page.

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: Did you pass the dispatcher (dispatch object) down to the onSubmit method?

Comment: Thank you, I think that solved it! will provide feedback after some tests but for the most part everything looks to be working as indented now!